# I am doing object detection on yolov4 using colab. The yolov4_last_weights of my project not getting saved to the backup folder in the drive mounted

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolov4

[The last weights of the project is not getting saved in the backup folder in the drive mounted. So the program is getting disconnected or getting stop in the middle of the program. can anyone help out what to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucvDP.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the "/MyDrive/yolo/" directory exists? If not, you need to create it manually.
2. Are you sure you specified the backup folder in the `*.data` file?

[This](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/416) github issue covers more root causes for your problem.